# Get second item from Tuple which is List<T>

Tags: c#, .net

How can I get `List<IMyType>` from `List<Tuple<int, List<IMyType>>>`

```
var result = alg.Result; // Result return List<Tuple<int, List<IMyType>>>
List<IMyType> list = ???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Servy's answer is the best way to do that. Just keep in mind that if you don't remember the LINQ way of doing things, you can always do it the old way:

```
var list = new List<IMyType>();
foreach(var tuple in result)
    list.AddRange(tuple.Item2);
```

Answer (score 4):

`SelectMany` is used to transform each item in the collection to a sequence of something else, and then to flatten that sequence:

```
var flattenedSequence = list.SelectMany(pair => pair.Item2);
```